# How { } quantifier works?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
>>>
>>> re.search(r'^\d{3, 5}$', '90210')  # {3, 5} 3 or 4 or 5 times
>>> re.search(r'^\d{3, 5}$', '902101')  # {3, 5} 3 or 4 or 5 times
>>> re.search(r'^\w{3, 5}$', 'hello')  # {3, 5} 3 or 4 or 5 times
>>> re.search(r'^\w{3, 5}$', 'hell')  # {3, 5} 3 or 4 or 5 times
>>>
```

All of the above suppose to should work, with {} quantifier

---

Question:

Why `r'^\d{3, 5}$'` does not search for `'90210'`?

Comment: remove the space

Comment: your input must contains 3-5 digits not 6 digits. if you just remove `^` from your pattern, it will match 02101 and if you just remove `$` , matches 90210. if remove both `^` and `$` matches 90210.

Answer (score 6):

There should be no space between `{m` and `,` and `n}` quantifier:

```
>>> re.search(r'^\d{3, 5}$', '90210')  # with space


>>> re.search(r'^\d{3,5}$', '90210')  # without space
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fb9d6ba16b0>
>>> re.search(r'^\d{3,5}$', '90210').group()
'90210'
```

BTW, `902101` does not match the pattern, because it has 6 digits:

```
>>> re.search(r'^\d{3,5}$', '902101')
```

Comment: space within quantifier

Comment: @overexchange, [`+`, `?`, `*`, ... are also quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html).