# regex search window size

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a large document that I am running a regex on. Below is an example of a similar expression:

```
(?=( aExample| bExample)(?=.*(XX))(?=.*(P1)))
```

This works a lot of times, but sometimes due to other text within the document the condition is met by looking in the entire document, e.g., there might be 10 characters between "aExample" and "XX, but 1,000 characters between "XX" and "P1".  I would like to contain the expression to N characters (lets say 50 for the sake of the example) so that the regex is a little more conservative. Any help is appreciated.  How can I go about reducing the size of the window of the regex to N characters instead of the entire string/document? Thanks!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @revo - sorry I was not clear:  How can I go about reducing the size of the window of the regex to N characters instead of the entire string/document?

Comment: Showing some sample inputs would be helpful in recognizing the main issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How { } quantifier works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867088/how-quantifier-works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?=( aExample| bExample)(?=.{1,50}(XX))(?=.{1,50}(P1)))`

You want to limit the number of `.`s to look at so you can just use braces.